# How to save Cheat Engine modifications in a pnach file

Tags: emulation, cheats, pcsx2, cheat-engine

I am using many pnach files to cheat in many ps2 games and I can play them by using pcsx2 - The best playstation 2 emulator ever!

I also use Cheat Engine 6.5 to make even more cheats that do not exist in my pnach files, but this is very annoying to cheat with Cheat Engine, because the memory locations are always changing and moving to another locations every time either I continue playing the game or restart the game or the pcsx2.

I also auto assemble and inject game's code to cheat, but whenever I load a state or restart pcsx2, all changes I made with my code injection are lost! Even pointer scan, level and reference of Cheat Engine don't work with pcsx2, because this is every complicated emulator.

I have read that it makes many shift operations to calculate the addresses (of memory and assembly).

This is very annoying! I want to save these cheats I make with cheat engine.
I don't want every time to scan for the values I want to change and inject the same codes over and over again.

pnach files are very comfortable, because they don't require you do anything, but just playing the game and enjoy everything they give you, like infinite health, ammo and etc.

I wonder if there is a way in a pnach file, making all the cheats that I make by cheat engine, and if yes, then how exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the "wall of text". I have done a little formatting. Now it looks better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Now that I've actually used reading comprehension.

**Word of Warning:**

This process is almost entirely based on both how emulators work, and how memory is used. I've not actually worked with memory editing with emulators, so there may be some twists and caveats I'm unaware of.

**Wall o' Text:**

The main problem here, is that static pointers, and other static values, are dependent on games and applications that run in the OS. For most games an apps, Cheat Engine is pretty simple, because it's running in the exact same OS.

After all, what makes a value static, is that it always has the same offset to the process' base memory address. Since Cheat Engine attaches to the process, it always knows where that base address is.

However, when you're talking about an emulator - that emulator basically works as its own OS, with its own processes, that runs in its own memory. Cheat Engine can easily attach to the emulator's process, but as it can't attach to the game itself, it doesn't know where that game's base memory is. Even worse, since the base memory is stored in dynamic memory, even the game's static memory will change location, from Cheat Engine's perspective.

However, since the emulator obviously needs to know where that base address is, that address works no differently than any other value you use Cheat Engine for. In other words, pcsx2 should have a static pointer, that points to that address. Once you have that pointer to that base address, you're halfway there.

The next half is using "what accesses this address" and "what writes to this address", along with the disassembler to trace the value you want to track, back to a static pointer within the game. Unfortunately this will require a fair bit of trial and error, because the only way you'll know if that pointer is static, is if its offset to the game's base address never changes. The only way you'll be able to check *that* is by closing and reopening the emulator a few times. Thankfully, by this point - you'll at least have the pointer to that base address.

When you're done, you'll have something that looks roughly like this:

static pointer(pcsx2)->base address(game)+offset to static pointer(game)->value(game)

Obviously, there's always the good chance that there may be some dynamic pointers in between, on either or both sides.

Hopefully this gets you on the right track,

Comment: Dear Digital_Utopia, your answer is very nice and clear, but not to my question. You didn't read all my question. I have already said that I have already tried pointers and pointer scan, but they don't work, because pcsx2 is very complicated emulator. For example, I have found the address 21940FCC. Then I searched for 21940FCC values and I got 0 found. I have read already that pcsx2 does shift operations to calculate it's pointers. I have already tried what you are suggesting me, but this just doesn't work! I need to work with the pnach files this is the only way!

Comment: My apologies, I misread it. The problem with an emulator, is that the games played within, are relative to the emulator itself - and not, relative to the operating system you're running CE in. 

So, the pointer scan won't work for the values. You'd actually have to find the pointer to where the game's memory starts, and then treat that game as a separate application, using "what accesses" and "what writes", combined with the disassembler to work out where the game's static pointers are. 

Unfortunately, this is well beyond my skillset.

Comment: I have already tried "what accesses" and "what writes" options. This allowed me to auto assemble and inject some binary codes for very funny cheats! But still I don't know how to find with them the static address. pcsx2 also changes the entry point of these instructions every time I load state or restart the emulator! Remember that my purpose is to cheat only with pnach files eventually. The cheats that I do with cheat engine I want to do with pnach files without cheat engine at all! This is what I want to learn and achieve.

Comment: Alright, forget the value, for right now. The first thing you need to find is the static pointer within pcsx2, to the base memory address of the PS2 game's memory. All static memory in the game, will always be relative to that base address. Your end result will look something like: pcsx2 static pointer -> PS2 game's base address + offset to PS2 game's static pointer -> value.

Comment: That sounds very complicated. Can I use the pcsx2 static pointer in a pnach file? And by the way, your last comment should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Well, yes. It is both pretty complicated - and once you are able to trace everything back to a pcsx2 static pointer, you should be able to use that like any other pointer, to any other value - pnach included.  And you're right, I'll write this up as an answer - though be warned, this is entirely logic based. There may be some twists and/or caveats I'm unaware of.

Comment: Can you tell me please how do I find pcsx2 static pointer and PS2 game's base address please?

Comment: Like I said, this is a bit outside my skill set; but I'd start by googling information on PS2 game memory editing, to see if there are any easy to search for static values. If there are such values, the offset listed in whatever information you find, should also be the offset to the base address, used by pcsx2. 

Unfortunately, beyond that I really can't help you any further - as I'd be in the same general spot you are now.